# Use custom model for OpenCV DNN Text Recognition

Tags: python, c++, opencv, onnx

I want to get text from an image using the OpenCV library in C++. I also have a trained model in python that recognizes my images without problems. But unfortunately my model is not suitable because it contains dynamic shape on input and output. I found a solution on Github, it uses a custom model:

https://github.com/Qengineering/OpenCV_OCR_DNN

I tried it and everything works without problems for the test data in the repository, but not for mine, I have a different vocabulary and completely different images. Can you please tell me how can I train the model to work with opencv Text Recognition in python? Maybe I can retrain the model from the repository somehow?